# Wordpress - Old theme causing display issues

Tags: theme-development

PROBLEM FIXED - *Server side cache not deleting. Now using "WP Fastest Cache"*

A WP site was using Adventurous theme which no longer suited us. We have changed, in the interim, to a WP Twenty theme which displays properly as long as I am logged in as admin. When I log out, the old theme appears on the live website.
When I access a page from the menu, it opens with the new theme correctly displayed. This remains constant over any other page opened.
When the Site Title is clicked the display reverts to the old theme.
In the DB the home url and the site url are identical and in the format  https://notavalidsite.zyx/ - I have cleared caches, queried hosting provider, done health checks, disabled plugins. If I access it from my phone, I have the same issue but if I use partners phone the site url displays correctly the new theme. So I go back to my phone, clear cache etc to no avail.
My skill level is somewhere around eager beginner and I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: When you say you've cleared the cache, do you mean the browser cache or the server cache (assuming you're using a caching plugin on your site)?

Answer (score 0):

Open a new browser tab as incognito and try. It seems to be a caching issue. My guess it is fine and it is just cached on your browser since you have visited before.

Comment: Opened a new incognito window. Cleared cache/cookies again, rebooted and retried. It doesn't fix the problem. I'm about to delete the menu bar and recreate it in the 2017 theme. Will post back if anything results (or not).

Comment: Problem resolved - server cache not deleted.